# How cordova is able to do API calls for different platforms

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am a beginner to the Phone-Gap framework for Mobile App Development. I have come to know that we can perform native API calls from the JavaScript  for every platform using Cordova.

I want to know how it is possible to perform native calls through Cordova using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how PhoneGap works in general? If so, remember that Cordova (the open source project) is, well, open source. You can look at the code and see for yourself. In general, the cordova.js file provides an interface between your HTML/JS code and plugins that interact with the native device. So on iPhone, for example, the generic Contacts API interacts with iOS specific plugins to get you your contact data, and on Android the same JS API withs with an Android native plugin. Basic idea is - provide the same JS hook but speak to a device specific set of code.

Comment: from where I see the implementation of cordova.js ? @Raymond

Comment: Um - download it? It's open source. :)

Comment: what cordova.js can do why can't I write my own js to do that

Comment: cordova.js provides a hook between your HTML/JS and plugins to allow for things you *can't* do in JS now. For example, while there is a Vibration API, it isn't actually yet supported in Android/web view yet. The Cordova JS library makes this work. In other cases it *isn't* required. Geolocation, for example, works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Applications are run in a container, it can "translate" javascript calls into native calls.

Application "talks" with its Cordova container and container sends native calls to device's OS (iOS, Android, etc.)

Comment: Although not the complete answer that people coming here are looking but better than the other answer. Thus, upvoted.